# Backend not working after changing the docroot to /pub

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

I have recently changed the `docroot` of Magento to `/pub`. I followed the official guide and then when I see the images are all broken and the admin URL is not working. It shows a page not found in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

check that your webserver serves the requests from the `<magento_folder>/pub` as well. Basically this is the `DocumentRoot` directive in Apache or `root` in nginx.

Comment: I have checked it and it is properly configured. I'm using Apache and the DocumentRoot is set to magento_root/pub

Comment: is it possible that you are running magento in a subfolder?

Comment: I have Magento in /var/www/html/

Answer (score 0):

You can set back from database as well.
from database section open table `"core_config"` and search for `"web/unsecure/base_url"` and "web/secure/base_url" and revert your changes for get back site.

hope this help.

Comment: Both are pointing to the same domain, and the frontend is working fine only issue is with the product images and backend url not working.

Comment: Have you checked in env.php file admin identifier for access admin??